# Cypher Return Node with MAX(n.property)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

With `Cypher`, I'm trying to return the node of the highest score. However it either just returns the score without any id to the node, what do I need to add to my query?

```
start n=node(*) WHERE HAS(n.score) return MAX(n.score);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution should give you both the score and node.

```
start n=node(*) WHERE HAS(n.score) RETURN n, n.score ORDER BY n.score LIMIT 1
```

Comment: but n will return the whole collection of nodes and not just the node with the highest score

Comment: Oops. I've edited my answer to what should be a working solution.

Comment: if I do

start n=node(*) WHERE HAS(n.score) RETURN n, n.score ORDER BY n.score DESC Limit 1;

that works, the other way would give me the lowest score.

Comment: How does this solution work in terms of performance with large set of nodes?